# Is it possible to run a java file with just the file name and arguments?

Tags: java

I understand this is how you would normally run a java program:

```
java filename arg0 arg1 arg2
```

Is it possible to create an executable file or some file that can run the program like this:

```
shortcutName arg0 arg1 arg2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to make it executable
try [jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) or [jar2exe](http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch or shell script? Launch4J?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at launcher solutions like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)